# Why does my Postal Card validation code fail [Hackerrank]?

Tags: python, regex

I'm solving the following challenge, and the code I wrote is correct (I know that after comparing my code with discussions), however the testcases fail. please have a look to the problem and confirm my code is good.

```py
regex_integer_in_range = r"^[1-9][0-9]{5}$"
regex_alternating_repetitive_digit_pair = r"(\d)(?=\d\1)"

import re
P = input()

print (bool(re.match(regex_integer_in_range, P)) 
and len(re.findall(regex_alternating_repetitive_digit_pair, P)) < 2)
```

When running the program, some odd error says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 53, in <module>
    request = json.load(open(run_directory + "request.json"))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'request.json'
```

Comment: I think this is an error by the Hackerrank.

Comment: I have sent them a request to look into it.

Comment: same problem here, both on "Postal Code Validation" and "Matrix Script"

Answer (score 1):

please try running the same

```
regex_integer_in_range = r"^[1-9][0-9]{5}$" # Do not delete 'r'.
regex_alternating_repetitive_digit_pair = r"(\d)(?=\d\1)"   # Do not delete 'r'.


import re
P = input()

print (bool(re.match(regex_integer_in_range, P)) 
and len(re.findall(regex_alternating_repetitive_digit_pair, P)) < 2)
```

Comment: you just added comments to the same code, does it work, if so can you explain how?